# Adding several y axes with zoom / pan in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a horizontal line chart in d3js that displays several lines based on json input. It has zooming and panning, but also need to display a y-axis for each of the drawn lines. In my case, three.

First off, is this bad practice? Should I stack all three on one side, or should I keep two on the left, one on the right or any other combination?

I've tried following [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/using-multiple-axes-for-d3js-graph.html), but that did really just create more mess and confusing code.

I was hoping someone could guide me in the direction of how to add the additional y axes and how I could have them work with the zooming and panning as well, like the one I have now.

Here's my current view:
[image]

And here's my code:

```
 <script>

        var margin = { top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 40 },
            width = ($("#trendcontainer").width() - 50) - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 650 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg;

        var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").parse;
        var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width]);

        var y0 = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var y1 = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var color = d3.scale.category10();
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickSize(-height);
        // TODO: Rename axis to instrument name (i.e 'depth')
        var yAxis0 = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y0)
            .orient("left")
            .tickSize(-width);

        var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y1)
            .orient("right")
            .tickSize(-width);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("basis")
            .x(function(d) {
                return x(d.date);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return y0(d.value);
            });

        d3.json('@Url.Action("DataBlob", "Trend", new {id = Model.Unit.UnitId, runId = Request.Params["runId"]})', function(error, tmparray) {
            var json = JSON.parse(tmparray);

            $('#processing').hide();

            color.domain(d3.keys(json[0]).filter(function(key) {
                return key !== "Time" && key !== "Id";
            }));

            json.forEach(function(d) {
                var date = format(d.Time);
                d.Time = date;
            });

            var instruments = color.domain().map(function(name) {
                return {
                    name: name,
                    values: json.map(function(d) {
                        return {
                            date: d.Time,
                            value: +d[name]
                        };
                    })
                };
            });

            x.domain(d3.extent(json, function(d) {
                return d.Time;
            }));
            y0.domain([
                d3.min(instruments, function (c) {
                    if (c.name == "Depth") {
                        return d3.min(c.values, function (v) {
                            return v.value;
                        });
                    }
                    //return d3.min(c.values, function (v) {
                    //    return v.value;
                    //});
                }),
                d3.max(instruments, function(c) {
                    return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
                        return v.value;
                    });
                })
            ]);

            y1.domain([
                d3.min(instruments, function (c) {
                    console.log("In y1.domain c is: " + c);
                    if (c.name == "Weight") {
                        return d3.min(c.values, function (v) {
                            return v.value;
                        });
                    }
                    //return d3.min(c.values, function (v) {
                    //    return v.value;
                    //});
                }),
                d3.max(instruments, function(c) {
                    return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
                        return v.value;
                    });
                })
            ]);

            var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                .x(x)
                .y(y0)
                .scaleExtent([1, 10])
                .on("zoom", zoomed);

            svg = d3.select(".panel-body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                .call(zoom)
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

            svg.append("rect")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis0);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis1);

            var instrument = svg.selectAll(".instrument")
                .data(instruments)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "instrument");

            instrument.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    return line(d.values);
                })
                .style("stroke", function(d) {
                    return color(d.name);
                });

            instrument.append("text")
                .datum(function(d) {
                    return {
                        name: d.name,
                        value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
                    };
                })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y0(d.value.value) + ")";
                })
                .attr("x", 3)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                });
        });

        function zoomed() {
            svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
            svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis0);
            svg.select(".x.grid")
                .call(make_x_axis()
                    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                    .tickFormat(""));
            svg.select(".y.grid")
                .call(make_y_axis()
                    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                    .tickFormat(""));
            svg.selectAll(".line")
                .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
        };

        var make_x_axis = function() {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                .ticks(5);
        };

        var make_y_axis = function() {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y0)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(5);
        };
</script>
```

Finally, here's what I'm trying to achieve (This component is way too slow, and does not handle large datasets well):
[image]

Comment: Do you need three axes or could you show all lines with the same axis? The tutorial you've linked to explains it quite nicely -- maybe you would find it easier to start with a smaller example?

Comment: Hi (again :)) Lars. Yes, I do need all axes.My problem in regards to the tutorial is that my data is in another format. As you might remember (or read out of this for that matter) is that I get my data with json, which sort of complicates it in my head. I've updated my above code with a though I had on setting the domains.

Comment: Well it looks like you're not drawing the second axis at all -- is that what you're struggling with?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to update image. The axis is drawn, but with the same values I guess. (Just using the two axes for now - can add a third later when this is sorted out)

Comment: It looks like the axis is drawn correctly. How would you like it to be different?

Comment: Take a look at the updated question. Attached an image of the old component, which does not handle large amounts of data very well. (Hence trying to recreate a new one in D3js with complete control of the component ourselves). Basically, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: So it's only a question of styling? It looks like you can achieve what's in the picture by adding a bit of space between the axes and using the default styling (tick lengths etc).

Comment: Might be 'only' that. However, also a question of being able to connect the zooming and panning to all three y-axes. As of right now, only the first y0 axis is reacting to zoom and pan.

Comment: You need to update the domains of the other axes in your `zoomed` handler function. The domain of the first axis gives you the "points" you need to update to.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help @LarsKotthoff! :) I'll post the answer once sorted out.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Ended up taking another approach, which seems a bit more clean (codewise) to me. Still not able to zoom though, and now all I do is zoom a grid behind the actual lines. Also, my timestamp is off again. Could you possibly provide some tips? See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwinger/k2j6a/

Comment: Well, you're not parsing the timestamps, so you don't have `Date` objects for your x axis. You're also not binding any data to the lines, so this way of updating them won't work. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/k2j6a/1/ -- I've updated one of the lines to work there. The other lines need to be updated in a similar manner, after setting the domain of the respective scales.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51254/discussion-between-nicklas-winger-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally ended up at a solution, with some kind assistance from @LarsKotthoff. Also added multiple axes zoom, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544200/zoom-left-and-right-axis-for-dual-scaled-chart-in-d3).

```
<script>
    /* d3 vars */
    var x;
    var y1;
    var y2;
    var y3;
    var graph;
    var m = [];
    var w;
    var h;

    /* d3 axes */
    var xAxis;
    var yAxisLeft;
    var yAxisLeftLeft;
    var yAxisRight;

    /* d3 lines */
    var line1;
    var line2;
    var line3;

    /* d3 zoom */
    var zoom;
    var zoomLeftLeft;
    var zoomRight;                           

    /* Data */
    var speed = [];
    var depth = [];
    var weight = [];
    var timestamp = [];

    var url = '@Url.Action("DataBlob", "Trend", new {id = Model.Unit.UnitId, runId = Request.Params["runId"]})';
    var data = $.getJSON(url, null, function(data) {
        var list = JSON.parse(data);
        var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").parse;
        list.forEach(function(d) {
            speed.push(d.Speed);
            depth.push(d.Depth);
            weight.push(d.Weight);
            var date = format(d.Time);
            d.Time = date;
            timestamp.push(d.Time);
        });

        m = [10, 80, 30, 100]; // margins: top, right, bottom, left
        w = $("#trendcontainer").width() - m[1] - m[3]; // width
        h = 550 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

        x = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(timestamp, function (d) {
            return d;
        })).range([0, w]);

        y1 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(speed)]).range([h, 0]);
        y2 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(depth)]).range([h, 0]);
        y3 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(weight)]).range([h, 0]);

        line1 = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("basis")
            .x(function (d, i) {
                return x(timestamp[i]);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y1(d);
            });

        line2 = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("basis")
            .x(function (d, i) {
                return x(timestamp[i]);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y2(d);
            });

        line3 = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("basis")
            .x(function (d, i) {
                return x(timestamp[i]);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y3(d);
            });

        zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .x(x)
            .y(y1)
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        zoomLeftLeft = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .x(x)
            .y(y3)
            .scaleExtent([1, 10]);

        zoomRight = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .x(x)
            .y(y2)
            .scaleExtent([1, 10]);

        // Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.
        graph = d3.select(".panel-body").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
            .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
            .call(zoom)
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

        // create xAxis
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(false);
        // Add the x-axis.
        graph.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        // create left yAxis
        yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1).ticks(10).orient("left");
        // Add the y-axis to the left
        graph.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "y axis axisLeft")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-15,0)")
            .call(yAxisLeft);

        // create leftleft yAxis
        yAxisLeftLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y3).ticks(10).orient("left");
        // Add the y-axis to the left
        graph.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "y axis axisLeftLeft")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-50,0)")
            .call(yAxisLeftLeft);

        // create right yAxis
        yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y2).ticks(10).orient("right");
        // Add the y-axis to the right
        graph.append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "y axis axisRight")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w + 15) + ",0)")
            .call(yAxisRight);

        // add lines
        // do this AFTER the axes above so that the line is above the tick-lines
        graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line1(speed)).attr("class", "y1");
        graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line2(depth)).attr("class", "y2");
        graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line3(weight)).attr("class", "y3");
    });

    function zoomed() {
        zoomRight.scale(zoom.scale()).translate(zoom.translate());
        zoomLeftLeft.scale(zoom.scale()).translate(zoom.translate());

        graph.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        graph.select(".y.axisLeft").call(yAxisLeft);
        graph.select(".y.axisLeftLeft").call(yAxisLeftLeft);
        graph.select(".y.axisRight").call(yAxisRight);
        graph.select(".x.grid")
            .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickFormat(""));
        graph.select(".y.axis")
            .call(make_y_axis()
                .tickSize(5, 0, 0));
        graph.selectAll(".y1")
            .attr("d", line1(speed));
        graph.selectAll(".y2")
            .attr("d", line2(depth));
        graph.selectAll(".y3")
            .attr("d", line3(weight));
    };

    var make_x_axis = function () {
        return d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(5);
    };

    var make_y_axis = function () {
        return d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y1)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(5);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please send a jsfiddle link for this? I really need this solution on an urgent basis.

Comment: @NicklasWinger What was your data format here ? Any chance you can share that?

Comment: @Gaurav51289 Sorry, but this was with a previous employer - I no longer have access to this project or code.